# How to call procedure inside cursor in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, mariadb

I'm new to MariaDB, I only have some experience in MS SQL Server.

I'm trying to call a procedure for every row returned from a query.

But I can't find the error when trying to create a procedure with a cursor.

I'm using Heidy to connect to MariaDB 10.0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  SetAll()

 BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE id INT ;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT aID FROM Customers ;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  testLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO id;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE testLoop;
    END IF;
    CALL SetById(id);
  END LOOP testLoop;

  CLOSE cur;
END
```

Error: "/* Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 */"

My precedure SetById(id) work just fine.

Comment: Use [Delimiters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delimiters/).

Comment: it works, thanks   @wchiquito